# How to combine and with or in bookshelfjs query builder?

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

I'm having problems with figuring out how to add multiple "and" queries that contain 'or' queries inside them

The result i want in the end is something like this:

```
select * from model where attribute1 = value1 and (attribute2 = value2 or attribute3 = value2)
```

This is the code I'm trying at the moment:

```
let result = await new Model().query(qb => {
   qb.where('attribute1', 'value1')

   qb.where(function () {
      this.where('attribute2', 'value2')
      this.orWhere('attribute3', 'value2')

   })
}).fetchAll()
```

But the thing is that the query only executes the first condition i write

If i put the parenthesis 'or' condition first the output is:

`select * from model where (attribute2 = value2 or attribute3 = value2)`

While if i put the normal condition first the output is :

`select * from model where attribute1 = value1`

The queries seem to not "append" (if that's the right word) with a 'and' statement

I know that if i use normal where statements the queries do 'append'

Example:

```
let result = await new Model().query(qb => {
   qb.where('attribute1', 'value1')
   qb.where('attribute2', 'value2')
}).fetchAll()
```

Outputs :

```
select * from model where attribute1 = value1 and attribute2 = value2
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like i was looking at the wrong query when i was using `qb.debug(true)` and they were very similar.

The code above works as intended. Sorry for any inconvenience.